# Neither xclip nor xsel in the following directory

Tags: python, linux

I just finished to made some modifications on a  script and I tried to execute it on terminal with Python but the terminal prompts the following:

> which: no xclip in (/usr/local/bin: /usr/bin: /bin: /usr/local/sbin: /usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/myUser/bin)
>
> which: no xsel in (/usr/local/bin: /usr/bin: /bin: /usr/local/sbin: /usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/myUser/bin)

This is the following script that I am trying to execute:

```
import random, sys, CipherEncryptionP

def main():
    random.seed(42)
        for i in range(20):
        message       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'*random.randint(4,40)
        message       = list(message)
        random.shuffle(message)
        print('Test #%s: "%s..."' % (i+1, message[:50]))
        for key in range(1,len(message)):
            encrypted = CipherEncryptionP.encryptMessage(message,key)
            print('Transposition cipher test passed. ')

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Finally, this is the CipherEncryptionP script that you need to run the code from above.

```
import pyperclip

def main():
    message        = raw_input("Give me your message: ")
    keyValue       = int(raw_input("Give a numeric value: "))
    ciphertext     = encryptMessage(message,keyValue)
    print(ciphertext + '|')
    pyperclip.copy(ciphertext)

def encryptMessage(message,keyValue):
    ciphertext=['']*keyValue
    for column in range(keyValue):
        pointer= column
        while pointer < len(message):
            ciphertext[column]+=message[pointer]
            pointer+=keyValue
    return ''.join(ciphertext)

if __name__== '__main_':
    main()
```

I am running a Scientific Linux 6.2 with kernel version 2.6.32-431.1.2.el6.x86_64 and the Python version is 2.6.6. You can download the pyperclip from the following page: http://invpy.com/pyperclip.py.

This first code is used test the second code which is a transposition cipher that I downloaded from http://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapter10.html.

All suggestions and modifications are welcome :)

Comment: Do you have `xclip` and `xsel` installed?

Comment: `which xclip`, `which xsel`. Then install them if they're not installed.

Comment: It throws the following: /usr/bin/which: no xclip in /usr/local/sbin: /usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/myUser/bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following package that installed xclip and xsel in my computer.

> rpm -ivh xclip-0.12-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm

Make sure to yum the following packages, otherwise, the above package will not be installed.

> yum -y install libc.so.6
>
> yum -y install libXmu.so.6

However, my program still is not executed by python because it appears the following address:

> /usr/bin/xclip

**Edited on February 3**

Finally my program worked and I found out that the problem was the first code.

```
import random, sys, CipherEncryptionP
random.seed(42)
    for i in range(20):
    message       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'*random.randint(4,40)
    message       = list(message)
    random.shuffle(message)
    print('Test #%s: "%s..."' % (i+1, message[:50]))
    for key in range(1,len(message)):
        encrypted = CipherEncryptionP.encryptMessage(message,key)
    print('Transposition cipher test passed. ')
```

I don't know what's the problem with the main function that I had at the beginning but this new fix definitely solved my problem.

**Editer on February 3**

At the end I discovered that the main function was missing an underscore, so I was able to run my program with that small fix. The problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

According the comments you don't have `xclip` or `xsel` installed. You can check what packages provide them with:

```
yum whatprovides xclip
```

outputs: xclip .... Do the same with xsel.

To install them both:

```
sudo yum install xclip xsel
```

To get the full path to the executable:

```
whereis -b xclip
```

or

```
which xclip
```

In case you don't have a repository that provides xsel/xclip you'll need to setup one. Here is an example: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/fedora-sl-centos-redhat6-enable-epel-repo/. On my CentOS Epel repo provides xsel.

Comment: There are no matches found.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am already installing your repository and I was able to fix my problem.